# How do you join tables from two different SQL Server instances in one SQL query

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-instances

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

How can I join two tables, which are located two different SQL Server instances, in one query?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best way I can think of to accomplish this is via [sp_addlinkedserver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx).  You need to make sure that whatever account you use to add the link (via [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)) has permissions to the table you're joining, but then once the link is established, you can call the server by name, i.e.:

```
SELECT *
FROM server1table
    INNER JOIN server2.database.dbo.server2table ON .....
```

Answer (score 9):

You can [create a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) and reference the table in the other instance using its fully qualified Server.Catalog.Schema.Table name.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server try Linked Server