# Can we do an inter server table join, in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was seeking for some data across servers, in some tables and I'm pretty new to SQL.. I might sound silly, but my question is how to bring two tables across servers together or join them rather so that I can view the data all together?

Comment: You need to create a linked server. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423907/how-do-you-join-tables-from-two-different-sql-server-instances-in-one-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of approaches you can use:

OPENROWSET:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Linked Servers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx