# sql query to return differences between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying to compare two tables, SQL Server, to verify some data. I want to return all the rows from both tables where data is either in one or the other. In essence, I want to show all the discrepancies. I need to check three pieces of data in doing so, FirstName, LastName and Product.

I'm fairly new to SQL and it seems like a lot of the solutions I'm finding are over complicating things. I don't have to worry about NULLs.

I started by trying something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [First Name], [Last Name], [Product Name] FROM [Temp Test Data]
WHERE ([First Name] NOT IN (SELECT [First Name] 
FROM [Real Data]))
```

I'm having trouble taking this further though.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Based on the answer by @treaschf I have been trying to use a variation of the following query:

```
SELECT td.[First Name], td.[Last Name], td.[Product Name]
FROM [Temp Test Data] td FULL OUTER JOIN [Data] AS d 
ON td.[First Name] = d.[First Name] AND td.[Last Name] = d.[Last Name] 
WHERE (d.[First Name] = NULL) AND (d.[Last Name] = NULL)
```

But I keep getting 0 results back, when I know that there is at least 1 row in td that is not in d.

EDIT:

Ok, I think I figured it out. At least in my few minutes of testing it seems to work good enough.

```
SELECT [First Name], [Last Name]
FROM [Temp Test Data] AS td
WHERE (NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT [First Name], [Last Name]
         FROM [Data] AS d
         WHERE ([First Name] = td.[First Name]) OR ([Last Name] = td.[Last Name])))
```

This is basically going to tell me what is in my test data that is *not* in my real data. Which is completely fine for what I need to do.

Comment: The EXCEPT example below is about 100x faster than this one.

Comment: can someone confirm if this works? doesn't work on my end, also don't see the point of "AS d" if "d" is not used anywhere, could there be a mistake there somewhere?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

IF you have tables `A` and `B`, both with colum `C`, here are the records, which are present in table `A` but not in `B`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON (A.C = B.C)
WHERE B.C IS NULL
```

To get all the differences with a single query, a full join must be used, like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
    FULL JOIN B ON (A.C = B.C)
WHERE A.C IS NULL OR B.C IS NULL
```

What you need to know in this case is, that when a record can be found in `A`, but not in `B`, than the columns which come from `B` will be NULL, and similarly for those, which are present in `B` and not in `A`, the columns from `A` will be null.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this working right, see my recent edit up top.

Comment: The problem might be that you cannot compare a value with null using '='. (Or at least when SET ANSI_NULLS is ON.) You must say: value IS NULL or value IS NOT NULL.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer I used because in doing this way I was able to easily do a few other things I had to later on.

Comment: `The objects "a.dbo.student" and "b.dbo.student" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.` I get error if table names are same and you pull them from two different databases.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter you need to change name of tables like `a.dbo.student as` and `b.dbo.student bs` then refer to tables with `as` and `bs`

Comment: Realy it Magic for me at least.

Answer (score 332):

```
(   SELECT * FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT * FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table1)
```

Comment: I get error using this. I am pulling the two tables from two different databases

Comment: Excellent! It worked for me and I'm pulling two tables from two different databases on two different servers.

Comment: I get an error as well, Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: If you're getting an error, you need to make sure you select the same fields (same types) in the same order. `SELECT *` works if this is the case for all columns; if not, just select some subset.

Comment: Anyone with experience on large datasets could tell me if this solution would work for tables with 500.000+  rows, what about 50 million rows?

Comment: Yes, and it is MINUS in Oracle and it is way more performant then the left outer join variants. I would be interested in the details why.

Comment: We use a different server with copies of our live tables as a test environment. For side by side testing with this kind of query on 2 different servers, this may provide additional help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22342227/1681303

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way I can add a field that will tell me which of the 2 tables the returned records are from?

Comment: @pokerplayer23 I added an answer that shows the source table here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41150408/255961

Comment: Be careful, as this solution discards duplicates.

Comment: If this query returns no results and its because of duplicates like someone said previously, use group by all columns having count(*) > 1 to find the added ones

Comment: Won't work in Big Query: `Message: EXCEPT must be followed by ALL, DISTINCT, or "("`

Comment: @motobói With BigQuery I'm facing the same issue. I found out that BigQuery only supports `EXCEPT DISTINCT`. Unfortunately, `EXCEPT ALL` is not supported by BigQuery.

Comment: @JuanVelez modify to `SELECT 'table1' in_table, * FROM (... EXCEPT ...) t1 UNION ALL SELECT 'table2', * FROM (... EXCEPT ...) t2`

Answer (score 38):

I know that this may not be a popular answer but I do agree with @Randy Minder on using third party tool when more complex comparison is needed.

This specific case here is easy and for this case such tools are not needed but this can get complex easily if you introduce more columns, databases on two servers, more complex comparison criteria and such.

There are a lot of these tools such as [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) or [Quest Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/) and you can always use them in trial mode to get the job done.

Comment: An example of a FOSS database-agnostic solution that works with any tabular sources of data from various databases or file systems is [Diffkit](http://www.diffkit.org/).

Comment: Microsoft also has a SQL Server `tablediff` command line utility referred to [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1073/sql-server-tablediff-command-line-utility/) .

Answer (score 23):

To get all the differences between two tables, you can use like me this SQL request :

```
SELECT 'TABLE1-ONLY' AS SRC, T1.*
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM Table1
      EXCEPT
      SELECT * FROM Table2
      ) AS T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE2-ONLY' AS SRC, T2.*
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM Table2
      EXCEPT
      SELECT * FROM Table1
      ) AS T2
;
```

Answer (score 16):

Simple variation on @erikkallen answer that shows which table the row is present in:

```
(   SELECT 'table1' as source, * FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT 'table2' as source, * FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table1)
```

---

If you get an error

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

then it may help to add

```
(   SELECT 'table1' as source, * FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT 'table1' as source, * FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT 'table2' as source, * FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT 'table2' as source, * FROM table1)
```

Comment: I get an error `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.` with this select. I had to add the `'table1' as source, ` part also to the Except-part. - I edited the answer for this.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get which column values are different, you could use Entity-Attribute-Value model:

```
declare @Data1 xml, @Data2 xml

select @Data1 = 
(
    select * 
    from (select * from Test1 except select * from Test2) as a
    for xml raw('Data')
)

select @Data2 = 
(
    select * 
    from (select * from Test2 except select * from Test1) as a
    for xml raw('Data')
)

;with CTE1 as (
    select
        T.C.value('../@ID', 'bigint') as ID,
        T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name,
        T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from @Data1.nodes('Data/@*') as T(C)    
), CTE2 as (
    select
        T.C.value('../@ID', 'bigint') as ID,
        T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name,
        T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from @Data2.nodes('Data/@*') as T(C)     
)
select
    isnull(C1.ID, C2.ID) as ID, isnull(C1.Name, C2.Name) as Name, C1.Value as Value1, C2.Value as Value2
from CTE1 as C1
    full outer join CTE2 as C2 on C2.ID = C1.ID and C2.Name = C1.Name
where
not
(
    C1.Value is null and C2.Value is null or
    C1.Value is not null and C2.Value is not null and C1.Value = C2.Value
)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1022c5/2)

Comment: Thanks, I've made this code a little bit dynamic. It now allows you to pass two tables you want to compare...

http://thitos.blogspot.com/2014/03/compare-data-from-two-tables.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use except , for example something like this :

```
-- DB1..Tb1 have values than DB2..Tb1 not have
Select Col1,Col2,Col3 From DB1..Tb1
except
Select Col1,Col2,Col3 From DB2..Tb1
-- Now we change order
-- DB2..Tb1 have values than DB1..Tb1 not have
Select Col1,Col2,Col3 From DB2..Tb1
except
Select Col1,Col2,Col3 From DB1..Tb1
```

Answer (score 4):

Presenting the Cadillac of Diffs as an SP.  See within for the basic template that was based on answer by @erikkallen.  It supports

- Duplicate row sensing (most other answers here do not)
- Sort results by argument
- Limit to specific columns
- Ignore columns (e.g. ModifiedUtc)
- Cross database tables names
- Temp tables (use as workaround to diff views)

### Usage:

```
exec Common.usp_DiffTableRows '#t1', '#t2';

exec Common.usp_DiffTableRows 
    @pTable0          = 'ydb.ysh.table1',
    @pTable1          = 'xdb.xsh.table2',
    @pOrderByCsvOpt   = null,  -- Order the results
    @pOnlyCsvOpt      = null,  -- Only compare these columns
    @pIgnoreCsvOpt    = null;  -- Ignore these columns (ignored if @pOnlyCsvOpt is specified)
```

### Code:

```
alter proc [Common].[usp_DiffTableRows]    
    @pTable0          varchar(300),
    @pTable1          varchar(300),
    @pOrderByCsvOpt   nvarchar(1000) = null,  -- Order the Results
    @pOnlyCsvOpt      nvarchar(4000) = null,  -- Only compare these columns
    @pIgnoreCsvOpt    nvarchar(4000) = null,  -- Ignore these columns (ignored if @pOnlyCsvOpt is specified)
    @pDebug           bit = 0
as
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose:  Compare rows between two tables.

      Usage:  exec Common.usp_DiffTableRows '#a', '#b';

    Modified    By          Description
    ----------  ----------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2015.10.06  crokusek    Initial Version
    2019.03.13  crokusek    Added @pOrderByCsvOpt
    2019.06.26  crokusek    Support for @pIgnoreCsvOpt, @pOnlyCsvOpt.    
    2019.09.04  crokusek    Minor debugging improvement
    2020.03.12  crokusek    Detect duplicate rows in either source table
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
begin try

    if (substring(@pTable0, 1, 1) = '#')
        set @pTable0 = 'tempdb..' + @pTable0; -- object_id test below needs full names for temp tables

    if (substring(@pTable1, 1, 1) = '#')
        set @pTable1 = 'tempdb..' + @pTable1; -- object_id test below needs full names for temp tables

    if (object_id(@pTable0) is null)
        raiserror('Table name is not recognized: ''%s''', 16, 1, @pTable0);

    if (object_id(@pTable1) is null)
        raiserror('Table name is not recognized: ''%s''', 16, 1, @pTable1);

    create table #ColumnGathering
    (
        Name nvarchar(300) not null,
        Sequence int not null,
        TableArg tinyint not null
    );

    declare
        @usp          varchar(100) = object_name(@@procid),    
        @sql          nvarchar(4000),
        @sqlTemplate  nvarchar(4000) = 
        '  
            use $database$;

            insert into #ColumnGathering
            select Name, column_id as Sequence, $TableArg$ as TableArg
              from sys.columns c
             where object_id = object_id(''$table$'', ''U'')
        ';          

    set @sql = replace(replace(replace(@sqlTemplate,
        '$TableArg$', 0),
        '$database$', (select DatabaseName from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier(@pTable0))),
        '$table$', @pTable0);

    if (@pDebug = 1)
        print 'Sql #CG 0: ' + @sql;

    exec sp_executesql @sql;

    set @sql = replace(replace(replace(@sqlTemplate,
        '$TableArg$', 1),
        '$database$', (select DatabaseName from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier(@pTable1))),
        '$table$', @pTable1);

    if (@pDebug = 1)
        print 'Sql #CG 1: ' + @sql;

    exec sp_executesql @sql;

    if (@pDebug = 1)
        select * from #ColumnGathering;

    select Name, 
           min(Sequence) as Sequence, 
           convert(bit, iif(min(TableArg) = 0, 1, 0)) as InTable0,
           convert(bit, iif(max(TableArg) = 1, 1, 0)) as InTable1
      into #Columns
      from #ColumnGathering
     group by Name
    having (     @pOnlyCsvOpt is not null 
             and Name in (select Value from Common.ufn_UsvToNVarcharKeyTable(@pOnlyCsvOpt, default)))
        or 
           (     @pOnlyCsvOpt is null
             and @pIgnoreCsvOpt is not null 
             and Name not in (select Value from Common.ufn_UsvToNVarcharKeyTable(@pIgnoreCsvOpt, default)))
        or 
           (     @pOnlyCsvOpt is null
             and @pIgnoreCsvOpt is null)

    if (exists (select 1 from #Columns where InTable0 = 0 or InTable1 = 0))
    begin
        select 1; -- without this the debugging info doesn't stream sometimes
        select * from #Columns order by Sequence;        
        waitfor delay '00:00:02';  -- give results chance to stream before raising exception
        raiserror('Columns are not equal between tables, consider using args @pIgnoreCsvOpt, @pOnlyCsvOpt.  See Result Sets for details.', 16, 1);    
    end

    if (@pDebug = 1)
        select * from #Columns order by Sequence;

    declare 
        @columns nvarchar(4000) = --iif(@pOnlyCsvOpt is null and @pIgnoreCsvOpt is null,
           -- '*',     
            (
              select substring((select ',' + ac.name
                from #Columns ac
               order by Sequence
                 for xml path('')),2,200000) as csv
            );

    if (@pDebug = 1)
    begin
        print 'Columns: ' + @columns;
        waitfor delay '00:00:02';  -- give results chance to stream before possibly raising exception
    end

    -- Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077929/538763
    --     - Added sensing for duplicate rows
    --     - Added reporting of source table location
    --
    set @sqlTemplate = '
            with 
               a as (select ~, Row_Number() over (partition by ~ order by (select null)) -1 as Duplicates from $a$), 
               b as (select ~, Row_Number() over (partition by ~ order by (select null)) -1 as Duplicates from $b$)
            select 0 as SourceTable, ~
              from 
                 (
                   select * from a
                   except
                   select * from b
                 )  anb
              union all
             select 1 as SourceTable, ~
               from 
                 (
                   select * from b
                   except
                   select * from a
                 )  bna
             order by $orderBy$
        ';    

     set @sql = replace(replace(replace(replace(@sqlTemplate, 
            '$a$', @pTable0), 
            '$b$', @pTable1),
            '~', @columns),
            '$orderBy$', coalesce(@pOrderByCsvOpt, @columns + ', SourceTable')
        );

     if (@pDebug = 1)
        print 'Sql: ' + @sql;

     exec sp_executesql @sql;

end try
begin catch
    declare        
        @CatchingUsp  varchar(100) = object_name(@@procid);    

    if (xact_state() = -1)
        rollback;    

    -- Disabled for S.O. post

    --exec Common.usp_Log
        --@pMethod = @CatchingUsp;

    --exec Common.usp_RethrowError        
        --@pCatchingMethod = @CatchingUsp;

    throw;
end catch
go

create function Common.Trim
(
    @pOriginalString nvarchar(max), 
    @pCharsToTrim nvarchar(50) = null -- specify null or 'default' for whitespae 
)  
returns table
with schemabinding
as 
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose:   Trim the specified characters from a string.

    Modified    By              Description
    ----------  --------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    2012.09.25  S.Rutszy/crok   Modified from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133044/9415    
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
return
with cte AS
(
  select patindex(N'%[^' + EffCharsToTrim + N']%', @pOriginalString) AS [FirstChar],
         patindex(N'%[^' + EffCharsToTrim + N']%', reverse(@pOriginalString)) AS [LastChar],
         len(@pOriginalString + N'~') - 1 AS [ActualLength]
   from
   (
         select EffCharsToTrim = coalesce(@pCharsToTrim, nchar(0x09) + nchar(0x20) + nchar(0x0d) + nchar(0x0a))
   ) c
)
select substring(@pOriginalString, [FirstChar],
                 ((cte.[ActualLength] - [LastChar]) - [FirstChar] + 2)
       ) AS [TrimmedString]
       --
       --cte.[ActualLength],
       --[FirstChar],
       --((cte.[ActualLength] - [LastChar]) + 1) AS [LastChar]              
from cte;
go

create function [Common].[ufn_UsvToNVarcharKeyTable] (
    @pCsvList     nvarchar(MAX),
    @pSeparator   nvarchar(1) = ','       -- can pass keyword 'default' when calling using ()'s
    )    
    --
    -- SQL Server 2012 distinguishes nvarchar keys up to maximum of 450 in length (900 bytes)
    -- 
    returns @tbl table (Value nvarchar(450) not null primary key(Value)) as
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose:  Converts a comma separated list of strings into a sql NVarchar table.  From

              http://www.programmingado.net/a-398/SQL-Server-parsing-CSV-into-table.aspx     

              This may be called from RunSelectQuery:

                  GRANT SELECT ON Common.ufn_UsvToNVarcharTable TO MachCloudDynamicSql;

    Modified    By              Description
    ----------  --------------  -------------------------------------------------------------------
    2011.07.13  internet        Initial version
    2011.11.22  crokusek        Support nvarchar strings and a custom separator.
    2017.12.06  crokusek        Trim leading and trailing whitespace from each element.
    2019.01.26  crokusek        Remove newlines
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/     
begin
    declare 
        @pos      int,
        @textpos  int,
        @chunklen smallint,
        @str      nvarchar(4000),
        @tmpstr   nvarchar(4000),
        @leftover nvarchar(4000),
        @csvList nvarchar(max) = iif(@pSeparator not in (char(13), char(10), char(13) + char(10)),
            replace(replace(@pCsvList, char(13), ''), char(10), ''),
            @pCsvList); -- remove newlines

    set @textpos = 1
    set @leftover = ''  
    while @textpos <= len(@csvList)
    begin
        set @chunklen = 4000 - len(@leftover)
        set @tmpstr = ltrim(@leftover + substring(@csvList, @textpos, @chunklen))
        set @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen

        set @pos = charindex(@pSeparator, @tmpstr)
        while @pos > 0
        begin
            set @str = substring(@tmpstr, 1, @pos - 1)
            set @str = (select TrimmedString from Common.Trim(@str, default));
            insert @tbl (value) values(@str);
            set @tmpstr = ltrim(substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr)))
            set @pos = charindex(@pSeparator, @tmpstr)
        end

        set @leftover = @tmpstr
    end

    -- Handle @leftover

    set @str = (select TrimmedString from Common.Trim(@leftover, default));

    if @str <> ''
       insert @tbl (value) values(@str);

    return
end
GO

create function Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier(@pIdentifier nvarchar(300))
returns @table table 
(    
    InstanceName          nvarchar(300) not null,
    DatabaseName          nvarchar(300) not null,
    SchemaName            nvarchar(300),
    BaseName              nvarchar(300) not null,
    FullTempDbBaseName    nvarchar(300),            -- non-null for tempdb (e.g. #Abc____...)
    InstanceWasSpecified  bit not null,
    DatabaseWasSpecified  bit not null,
    SchemaWasSpecified    bit not null,
    IsCurrentInstance     bit not null,
    IsCurrentDatabase     bit not null,
    IsTempDb              bit not null,
    OrgIdentifier         nvarchar(300) not null
) as
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Purpose:  Split a Sql Server Identifier into its parts, providing appropriate default values and
              handling temp table (tempdb) references.

    Example:  select * from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier('t')
              union all
              select * from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier('s.t')
              union all
              select * from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier('d.s.t')
              union all
              select * from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier('i.d.s.t')
              union all
              select * from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier('#d')
              union all
              select * from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier('tempdb..#d'); 

              -- Empty
              select * from Common.ufn_SplitDbIdentifier('illegal name'); 

    Modified    By              Description
    ----------  --------------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2013.09.27  crokusek        Initial version.  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
begin
    declare 
        @name nvarchar(300) = ltrim(rtrim(@pIdentifier));

    -- Return an empty table as a "throw"
    --
    --Removed for SO post
    --if (Common.ufn_IsSpacelessLiteralIdentifier(@name) = 0)
      --  return;

    -- Find dots starting from the right by reversing first.

    declare 
        @revName nvarchar(300) = reverse(@name);

    declare
        @firstDot int = charindex('.', @revName);

    declare
        @secondDot  int = iif(@firstDot = 0,  0, charindex('.', @revName, @firstDot + 1));

    declare
        @thirdDot   int = iif(@secondDot = 0, 0, charindex('.', @revName, @secondDot + 1));

    declare
        @fourthDot  int = iif(@thirdDot = 0, 0, charindex('.', @revName, @thirdDot + 1));

    --select @firstDot, @secondDot, @thirdDot, @fourthDot, len(@name);

    -- Undo the reverse() (first dot is first from the right).
    --
    set @firstDot = iif(@firstDot = 0, 0, len(@name) - @firstDot + 1);
    set @secondDot = iif(@secondDot = 0, 0, len(@name) - @secondDot + 1);
    set @thirdDot = iif(@thirdDot = 0, 0, len(@name) - @thirdDot + 1);
    set @fourthDot = iif(@fourthDot = 0, 0, len(@name) - @fourthDot + 1);

    --select @firstDot, @secondDot, @thirdDot, @fourthDot, len(@name);

    declare
        @baseName   nvarchar(300)  = substring(@name, @firstDot + 1, len(@name) - @firstdot);

    declare
        @schemaName nvarchar(300) = iif(@firstDot - @secondDot - 1 <= 0, 
                                        null,
                                        substring(@name, @secondDot + 1, @firstDot - @secondDot - 1));
    declare
        @dbName     nvarchar(300) = iif(@secondDot - @thirdDot - 1 <= 0, 
                                        null,
                                        substring(@name, @thirdDot + 1, @secondDot - @thirdDot - 1));
    declare
        @instName   nvarchar(300) = iif(@thirdDot - @fourthDot - 1 <= 0, 
                                        null, 
                                        substring(@name, @fourthDot + 1, @thirdDot - @fourthDot - 1));

    with input as (
        select
           coalesce(@instName, '[' + @@servername + ']') as InstanceName,
           coalesce(@dbName,     iif(left(@baseName, 1) = '#', 'tempdb', db_name())) as DatabaseName,
           coalesce(@schemaName, iif(left(@baseName, 1) = '#', 'dbo', schema_name())) as SchemaName,
           @baseName as BaseName,
           iif(left(@baseName, 1) = '#',
               (
                  select [name] from tempdb.sys.objects
                  where object_id = object_id('tempdb..' + @baseName)
               ), 
               null) as FullTempDbBaseName,                
           iif(@instName is null, 0, 1) InstanceWasSpecified,       
           iif(@dbName is null, 0, 1) DatabaseWasSpecified,
           iif(@schemaName is null, 0, 1) SchemaWasSpecified    
     )
     insert into @table           
     select i.InstanceName, i.DatabaseName, i.SchemaName, i.BaseName, i.FullTempDbBaseName,
            i.InstanceWasSpecified, i.DatabaseWasSpecified, i.SchemaWasSpecified,
            iif(i.InstanceName = '[' + @@servername + ']', 1, 0) as IsCurrentInstance,
            iif(i.DatabaseName = db_name(), 1, 0) as IsCurrentDatabase,
            iif(left(@baseName, 1) = '#', 1, 0) as IsTempDb,
            @name as OrgIdentifier
       from input i;

    return;
end
GO
```

Comment: I hit a few issues where the sql string was > 4000 characters, changing the declares to     (a)columns nvarchar(max), (a)sql  nvarchar(max), (a)sqlTemplate  nvarchar(max) fixed that. This a fantastic piece of work

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    [First Name], [Last Name]
FROM 
    [Temp Test Data] AS td EXCEPTION JOIN [Data] AS d ON 
         (d.[First Name] = td.[First Name] OR d.[Last Name] = td.[Last Name])
```

Much simpler to read.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick, similar with [Tiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25763204/4206531)'s solution, return "source" table as well.

```
select [First name], [Last name], max(_tabloc) as _tabloc
from (
  select [First Name], [Last name], 't1' as _tabloc from table1
  union all
  select [First name], [Last name], 't2' as _tabloc from table2
) v
group by [Fist Name], [Last name]
having count(1)=1
```

result will contain differences between tables, in column _tabloc you will have table reference.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple smoke test where you you're trying to ensure two tables match w/out worrying about column names:

```
--ensure tables have matching records
Select count (*) from tbl_A
Select count (*) from tbl_B

--create temp table of all records in both tables
Select * into #demo from tbl_A 
Union All
Select * from tbl_B

--Distinct #demo records = Total #demo records/2 = Total tbl_A records = total tbl_B records
Select distinct * from #demo
```

You can easily write a store procedure to compare a batch of tables.

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance issue related with the left join as well as full join with large data.

In my opinion this is the best solution:

```
select [First Name], count(1) e from
(select * from [Temp Test Data]
 union all
 select * from [Temp Test Data 2]) a
group by [First Name] having e = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`EXCEPT` and `NOT EXISTS` are good ways to quickly find differences between sets of data, but I often want to know exactly which columns are different and how they are different.

What I find useful in these situations is using `UNPIVOT` to convert columns into key value pairs that one can compare row for row.

In order to be useful though, there needs to be a way to match the records you want to compare, in your example something like a social security number or a "person id":

```
CREATE TABLE [RealData] 
(
  [PersonId] INT,
  [FirstName] NVARCHAR(100), 
  [LastName] NVARCHAR(100),
  [ProductName] NVARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE [TempTestData] 
(
  [PersonId] INT,
  [FirstName] NVARCHAR(100), 
  [LastName] NVARCHAR(100),
  [ProductName] NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO [RealData] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [ProductName])
VALUES 
(1, 'Al', 'Bundy', 'Ladies Size 12'),
(2, 'Peggy', 'Bundy', 'TV Guide')

INSERT INTO [TempTestData] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [ProductName])
VALUES 
(1, 'Al', 'Bundy', 'Ladies Size 13'),
(2, 'Peggy', 'Bundy', 'TV Guide')
```

And the `UNPIVOT` with a couple of CTEs thrown in:

```
;WITH RealDataCte AS (
  SELECT 
   'Real Data' AS [DataSource],
   unpivotedRealData.* 
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      CAST([PersonId] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [PersonId],
      [FirstName],
      [LastName], 
      [ProductName]
    FROM [RealData]) AS realData
  UNPIVOT
  (ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN ([FirstName], [LastName],  [ProductName])) AS unpivotedRealData
),
TempTestDataCte AS (
  SELECT 
    'Temp Test Data' AS [DataSource],
     unpivotedDempTestData.* 
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      CAST([PersonId] AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS [PersonId],
      [FirstName],
      [LastName], 
      [ProductName]
    FROM [TempTestData]) AS tempTestData
  UNPIVOT
  (ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN ([FirstName], [LastName],  [ProductName])) AS unpivotedDempTestData
)
SELECT
  RealDataCte.[DataSource],
  RealDataCte.[ColumnName],
  RealDataCte.[ColumnValue],
  TempTestDataCte.[DataSource],
  TempTestDataCte.[ColumnName],
  TempTestDataCte.[ColumnValue],
  CASE WHEN RealDataCte.[ColumnValue] <> TempTestDataCte.[ColumnValue] THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS ColumnsDiffer
FROM RealDataCte
INNER JOIN
TempTestDataCte 
ON RealDataCte.[ColumnName] = TempTestDataCte.[ColumnName] 
AND RealDataCte.[PersonId] = TempTestDataCte.[PersonId] 
WHERE 
RealDataCte.[ColumnValue] <> TempTestDataCte.[ColumnValue]
```

The result - the 2 products are different:

[image]

This is great if you have many, many columns to compare over a large number of rows.

It can take a while to setup, though, and you do need to convert every column value to the same type, which can take a while (notice the `CAST` for PersonId).

If the dataset is really large you may also want to use temp tables instead of CTEs.

[SQL Fiddle Example Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/67847c/4)

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work just fine.
A select query to find difference between row counts of two different tables

`select (t1 - t2) as count_diff from (select (select count(*) from tbl1) t1, (select count(*) from tbl2) t2)`

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments because my reputation isn't high enough. That seems silly.

Replying to @Juan Velez in the top voted answer which gives the solution

```
(   SELECT * FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT * FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM table1)
```

and Juan asked, "How do I see which tables had which rows"?

This part of the query selects all rows in table 1 that are not in table 2

```
(   SELECT * FROM @table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @table2)
```

This part of the query selects all rows in table 2 that are not in table 1

```
(   SELECT * FROM @table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @table1)
```

UNION ALL just puts them together so you can, just from one table, see if any of them is missing rows that the other has. If you want to see the individual differences try

```
INSERT INTO @table1NotTable2
    SELECT * FROM @table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @table2

INSERT INTO @table2NotTable1
    SELECT * FROM @table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @table1
```

And to achieve the same final result as his answer, use

```
SELECT * FROM @table1NotTable2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM @table2NotTable1
```

For people wanting this as a copy/paste template:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (
    
)
DECLARE @table1NotTable2 TABLE (
    
)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (
    
)

DECLARE @table2NotTable1 TABLE (
    
)

INSERT INTO @table1 (
    
)

INSERT INTO @table2 (

)

INSERT INTO @table1NotTable2
    SELECT * FROM @table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @table2

INSERT INTO @table2NotTable1
    SELECT * FROM @table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @table1

SELECT * FROM @table1NotTable2
SELECT * FROM @table2NotTable1
SELECT * FROM @table1NotTable2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM @table2NotTable1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL UNION and EXCEPT operations can be used to compare entire datasets between source and target tables for data completeness and correctness. For example:

```
(SELECT * FROM source_table)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM target_table)
EXCEPT
(SELECT * FROM source_table INTERSECT SELECT * FROM target_table);
```

You can also try UNION ALL if you want the actual number rows.