# How to Compare two database tables by using QTP?

Tags: sql, automated-tests, qtp

I am using QTP to read two tables from database. 
Is there any function which can compare two tables row and column wise.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to compare them using SQL.  Seems like it would be simpler.  Check out this previous question:

[SQL query to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077807/sql-query-to-return-differences-between-two-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, the database checkpoint. Just use it, it is self-explaining. If it appears to be not, downvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Export the data from the tables to spreadsheets and compare them cell by cell.