# SQL query to return difference between table joined to itself

Tags: sql, left-join, sql-server-2012, self-join, not-exists

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have a view called **AdvApp.vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened**
I want to return all memberid's that are in portfoliogroupcode **master** or portfoliogroupcode **open** but are not in both groups. I don't care about members in other groups.

The following stackoverflow article is close to what I need, but doesn't seem to work when joining a table to itself.

[sql query to return differences between two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077807/sql-query-to-return-differences-between-two-tables).

This is my table.

```
PortfolioGroupCode  MemberID    MemberCode
master              316         abc
master              317         def
open                316         abc
open                317         def
open                321         ghi
master              322         jkl
closed               89         lmn
```

This is my desired result showing the delta between members of master and open.

```
PortfolioGroupCode  MemberID    MemberCode
open                321         ghi
master              322         jkl
```

I tried the following two queries, both from the aforementioned article.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM [AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened] a
FULL JOIN [AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened] b
ON (A.PortfolioGroupCode = B.PortfolioGroupCode)
WHERE A.PortfolioGroupCode IS NULL OR B.PortfolioGroupCode IS NULL
```

AND

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.membercode, a.portfoliogroupcode
FROM [AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened] a
WHERE (
NOT EXISTS (
SELECT b.membercode
FROM [AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened] b
WHERE a.PortfolioGroupCode = 'master'
AND b.PortfolioGroupCode = 'open'
))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct PortfolioGroupCode,  MemberID,    MemberCode 
from test 
where memberID not in (
     select distinct a.memberID from test a, test b
     where a.memberId = b.memberID 
     and a.PortfolioGroupCode in ('open','master')
     and a.PortfolioGroupCode <> b.PortfolioGroupCode) 
and PortfolioGroupCode in ('open','master')
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66e80/5)

Comment: the query analyzer is showing me an error where temp; is. I get this error with or without the semicolon. I can also remove temp; and the query runs butthis is not the correct result. Thanks

Comment: I can get your test to work but for some reason in the actual database the result returned is blank?

Comment: I got it to work, perhaps I needed to mention master is bigger than open. Open is a subset of master. I will include the working query above.

Answer (score 0):

This works note the disctinction with  these lines

```
 and a.PortfolioGroupCode = 'master'
 and b.PortfolioGroupCode = 'open'
```

**working query**

```
select distinct PortfolioGroupCode,  MemberID,    MemberCode 
from AdvApp.vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened  
where memberID not in (
     select distinct a.memberID from AdvApp.vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened  a, AdvApp.vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened  b
     where a.memberId = b.memberID 
     and a.PortfolioGroupCode = 'master'
     and b.PortfolioGroupCode = 'open'
     and a.PortfolioGroupCode <> b.PortfolioGroupCode) 
and PortfolioGroupCode in ('open','master')
```