# FULL sql version-control using Team Foundation Server

Tags: sql, visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops

**Team Foundation Server version-control of Web Applications**

I feel let down :(  ...

Checking-in and out .mdf files, branching and merge all work well in TFVC, however there is no data conflict resolution (conflict resolution for code is great!), only a choice is offered between whole source or target files.

I am not suggesting that data-tables are displayed side-by-side, because scripts in DAC/ 'database projects' can be compared for changes in table structure and [data differences compared by stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077807/sql-query-to-return-differences-between-two-tables).

Some method must be commonly used, but apparently that MS expect the code and data versioning to be managed iteratively/ separately?  (I would like to avoid trialling additional proprietary software like Red-Gate Source-Control.)

FULL version control is required as new feature branches will change the DB, but core/testing data needs to be retained.

So PLEASE!! Help me with pointers to straight-forward FULL version-control practices for web applications that include sql versioning with intelligent merge and roll-back capabilities.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Red Gate Deployment Manager](http://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/) to manage your deployments, which also comes with a free community edition. However, although not strictly mandatory we would recommend that you do this in conjunction with [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/), which would allow you to specify static data tables to put in version control. Although this is third party software, the database objects are saved as plain text .sql files, and not a proprietary format.

Comment: Seems the SQL source control is a free trial for 28 days, do you know an open source or free to MS Bizspark members option?