# How to check difference between two tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table relevancies, where there are 2 colums.
1. User_id (It has two users, one and two)
2. Ratings

***Now I want to know the difference between ratings of two users(1,2). The rating difference should be two.  ***

Table:
'`+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_ndcg_reporting |
+--------------------------+
| averages                 |
| last_visited_queries     |
| products                 |
| queries                  |
| query_types              |
| ratings                  |
| ratings_news             |
| relevancies              |
| schema_migrations        |
| sites                    |
| users                    |
+--------------------------+`

Inside relevancies:

```
`+-----+--------+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

| id  | rating | product_id | query_id | user_id | created_at |updated_at

| 726 |      5 |          1 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-11-24 12:43:07 |

| 727 |      5 |          2 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-11-24 12:43:21 |

| 728 |      5 |          3 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-11-24 12:43:31 |

| 729 |      5 |          4 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-11-24 12:43:32 |

| 730 |      4 |          5 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-11-24 12:43:53 |

| 731 |      5 |          6 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-11-24 12:43:55 |

| 732 |      4 |          7 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-12-28 10:25:52 |

| 733 |      4 |          8 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-12-27 12:44:24 |

| 734 |      5 |          9 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-11-24 12:44:01 |

| 735 |      4 |         10 |        1 |       2 | 2016-11-24 06:06:12 | 2016-12-28 10:25:53 |
`

Comment: which are the 2 tables here (mentioned in the question's title)? Could you provide some sample data for these two tables, and also a sample of what the result should look like?

Comment: I did not know anything, so I did not try anything

Comment: Possible Duplicate [sql query to return differences between two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077807/sql-query-to-return-differences-between-two-tables)

Comment: single table countain user_id, product_Id and ratings, and there are two users who rated some products. Now I want Product_Id which has ratings exceeded by 2. Example: User_1 rated 0 and user_2 rated 3 then i want product name. @ChitharanjanDas

Comment: Please try to add code you have so far and read how to do it properly [mcve]

Comment: please update your question. add information, table structures,...
with the information you currently provided it is impossible to help you.

Comment: I added data now.

Comment: @EstebanP. I added tables now.

Comment: Inside relevancy the data is from user 2

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a self-join, like so:

```
select a.product_id
from relevencies a inner join relevencies b
on a.product_id = b.product_id and a.user_id <> b.user_id and a.rating >= (b.rating + 2);
```

If a user can give only a single review for a product, you can remove the `a.user_id <> b.user_id` condition.

Comment: Hey I added data.