# Compare two identical tables and retrieve differential rows

Tags: sql, informix

Is there a way to compare two identical tables and retrieve differential rows in Informix DB?

Consider the below tables, where **ID** is the primary key.

```
TABLE A     

ID    NAME    EMAIL               PROFILE
a1    ABC     ABC@ymail.com       student  
a2    XYZ     XYZ@gmail.com       student
a3    LMN     LMN@gmail.com       Staff

TABLE B

ID    NAME    EMAIL               PROFILE
a1    ABC     ABC@ymail.com       student
a2    XYZ     XYZ@gmail.com       student
a3    LMN     LMN@ymail.com       student
```

Kindly help me in framing an SQL to retrieve rows from TABLE A which is not matching with TABLE B.

OUTPUT should be:

```
ID    NAME    EMAIL               PROFILE
a3    LMN     LMN@gmail.com       Staff
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077807/sql-query-to-return-differences-between-two-tables read this, might give you a idea

Comment: this is duplicate

Comment: did you try a search? there are so many examples already online here for your task

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE_A 
            LEFT JOIN TABLE_B   
                ON TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_B.ID
                    AND TABLE_A.[NAME] = TABLE_B.[NAME]
                    AND TABLE_A.EMAIL = TABLE_B.ID
                    AND TABLE_A.[PROFILE] = TABLE_B.[PROFILE]
WHERE   TABLE_B.[NAME] IS NULL
```

Comment: Be aware that the square bracket quoting notation is peculiar to MS SQL Server and Sybase — other DBMS do not support it.  In Informix, the use of 'name' and 'profile' as column names would not cause any issues unquoted.

Comment: Thanks Simone & Jonathan