# To add server using sp_addlinkedserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to insert values from one server to another server and I got the error:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1 Could not find server
>   'SNRJDI\SLAMANAGEMENT' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to
>   add the server to sysservers.

Answer (score 118):

I got it. It worked fine

Thank you for your help:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='Servername'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'Servername', 'false', NULL, 'username', 'password@123'
```

Comment: For the benefit of other users, you may want to mark your response as an `Answer`.

Answer (score 17):

Add the linked server first with

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'SNRJDI\SLAMANAGEMENT',
@srvproduct=N'',
@provider=N'SQLNCLI'
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: When I tried to execute above I got error like 'Msg 15028, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSaddserver_internal, Line 89
The server 'SNRJDI\SLAMANAGEMENT' already exists.'

Comment: Then When I execute the Query I got another error like'Msg 18452, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.'

Comment: How are you connecting to the server you are running from? You should be providing the server credentials as opposed to using a network service or windows logon.

Answer (score 11):

*I had  the same issue connecting an SQL_server 2008 to an SQL_server 2016 hosted in a remote server. @Domnic 's answer didn't worked for me straightforward. I write my tweaked solution here as I think it may be useful for someone else.*

An extended answer for remote IP db connections:

**Step 1: Link servers**

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='SRV_NAME',
   @srvproduct=N'',
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI',   
   @datasrc=N'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd';
   
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'SRV_NAME', 'false', NULL, 'your_remote_db_login_user', 'your_remote_db_login_password'
```

...where `SRV_NAME` is an invented name. We will use it to refer to the remote server from our queries. `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` is the ip address of the remote server hosting your SQLserver DB.

**Step 2: Run your queries**
For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM [SRV_NAME].your_remote_db_name.dbo.your_table
```

...and that's it!

Syntax details: [sp_addlinkedserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 7):

-- check if server exists in table sys.server

```
select * from sys.servers
```

-- set database security

```
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
    RECONFIGURE
    GO

    EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
    RECONFIGURE
    GO
```

-- add the external dbserver

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='#servername#'
```

-- add login on external server

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin '#Servername#', 'false', NULL, '#username#', '#password@123"'
```

-- control query on remote table

```
select top (1000) * from [#server#].[#database#].[#schema#].[#table#]
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the only usefull answer for me. :)

Answer (score 5):

FOR SQL SERVER

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='servername'
```

No need to specify other parameters. You can go through this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql).

Comment: Apologies for the -1, looks like I clicked it by accident but noticed too late to undo.  Apparently if you do any edit I'll be able to change it.