# How to use two servers in one sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I need to try and use two different servers in one SQL statement. Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT p.FirstField 
from [FirstDatabase]..FirstTableName p 
Where not exists (select p2.SecondField 
from [SecondServer].[SecondDatabase]..SecondTableName p2 
where p.FirstField = p2.SecondField)
```

I do not use the First Server in the first part of the statement because that Server has already been selected.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Did you set up the second server as a linked server already?

Comment: try linked servers...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set up the remote server as a linked server using [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx). Then you can refer to the remote table using the `linked_server_name.catalog.schema.object_name` syntax. You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx).