# How to query 2 identical SQL Server databases on different server machines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query to select full list from 2 remote databases which are structurally identical, but on different server machines.

How to use `sp_addlinkedserver` to query the 2 databases in the same query?

To get something like this each database requires the same user name and password

```
SELECT  
   [Pays]
FROM  
   /// [db1].[dbo].[liste_pays] Union [db1].[dbo].[liste_pays]///
```

They even have the same name but different data inside

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server

Comment: Can you see both servers? I mean can you do SELECT [Pays] FROM [db1].[dbo].[liste_pays] and the same on other database?

Comment: Anyway the sintax of your query is wrong

Comment: i want a solution that alloaw me to make query like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose: 
You have a Server SR1, Database DB1 on  Schema SC1 Table tbl1 and column Pays.
You have a Server SR2, Database DB1 on  Schema SC1 Table tbl1 and column Pays.

First you will need to add a linked server relationship between SR1 and SR2.
Once that is established.
You can query something like this:

```
SELECT ABC.Pays FROM SR1.DB1.SC1.Tbl1 ABC
UNION ALL
SELECT DEF.Pays FROM SR2.DB1.SC1.Tbl1 DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) for a simple tutorial about how to create a linked server.

After creating linked server, we can query it as follows:

```
select * from LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use sp_addlinkedserver to create a server link. See the reference documentation for usage. Once the server link is established, you'll construct the query as normal, just prefixing the database name with the other server. I.E:

Reference Docs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

```
SELECT tab2.column_name  
FROM  [DB1.mdf].[dbo].[table_name_1] tab1 INNER JOIN [DB2.mdf].[dbo].[table_name_2]  tab2   
ON tab1.col_name = tab2.col_name
```