# jdbc and query multiple databases using single parameter

Tags: sql, jdbc, parameter-passing

What I am trying to accomplish: I have ambulance data in multiple databases. The gps of ambulance tracks in one database, dispatch records in another and medical records in a third. They all have in common a unique key leading back to a fire/ems incident. In this case I would like use JDBC to query two databases using a parameter. My parameter is a unique ID of an emergency incident. I want to accomplish a full report of an incident from multiple database sources based on that unique ID.
As you can see from my code shown below I am passing the parameter twice - once in each try catch block (preStatement.setString(1, "MLC140701045015");).

My goal is to have a gui with a drop down list. The user chooses an incident and a report is generated. The parameter is only passed once from a drop down list in a gui.

My question is: Can this parameter be passed only once?
I have a liberal arts degree, not a computer science degree. You cannot be too simplistic for me. Please be explicit in your reply.

```
   package javaDatabase;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class PreparedStatements
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // obtain information from dispatch
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try
        {
            conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection

("jdbc:sqlserver://999.99.99.99;database=Incidents;integratedsecurity=false;user=myUser;password=myPassw

ord");
            PreparedStatement preStatement = conn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT I_EventNumber, I_Address, 

I_tTimeDispatch FROM IIncident WHERE I_EventNumber = ?");
            // pass a parameter
            preStatement.setString(1, "MLC140701045015");

            ResultSet rset = preStatement.executeQuery();
            // output the results of the dispatch
            while (rset.next())
            {
                String IncidentID = rset.getString("I_EventNumber");
                String Address = rset.getString("I_Address");
                String dtmIncident = rset.getString("I_tTimeDispatch");

                System.out.println(IncidentID + ", " + Address + ", "
                        + dtmIncident);
            }
            // clean up the program and close the connections
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // obtain information from gps database.
        Connection avlconn = null;
        Statement avlstmt = null;
        try
        {
            avlconn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection

("jdbc:sqlserver://777.77.77.77;database=gps_tracks;integratedsecurity=false;user=myUser;password=myPass

");
            PreparedStatement preStatement = avlconn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT RTRIM(AssignedIncident) AS [Mission], 

RTRIM(CallSign) AS [Ambulance], RTRIM(UnitStatus) AS [Disposition], DateTimeStamp, Longitude, Latitude 

FROM HISTORY_201407 WHERE AssignedIncident = ?");
            // pass the same parameter previously. Why must this be done twice?
            preStatement.setString(1, "MLC140701045015");
            // return a result of the gps tracks
            ResultSet rset = preStatement.executeQuery();

            while (rset.next())
            {
                String mission = rset.getString("Mission");
                String truck = rset.getString("Ambulance");
                String disposition = rset.getString("Disposition");
                Date dateTime = rset.getDate("DateTimeStamp");
                Double longitude = rset.getDouble("Longitude");
                Double latitude = rset.getDouble("Latitude");
                System.out.println(mission + ", " + truck + ", " + disposition
                        + ", " + dateTime + ", " + longitude + ", " + latitude);
            }
            // clean up the program and close out the connections
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (avlstmt != null)
                    avlstmt.close();
                if (avlconn != null)
                    avlconn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do is to set up a Linked Server from one DB to the other. That will allow you to execute SQL to tables in both DBs while only being connect to one.  Here are some details on how to do that.

[Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

Once that is done can execute a query that does a SQL JOIN of the two tables (one local to the DB you connected to and one in the linked server DB) and pull back your results from both tables with a single query and result set.  Here is a pretty good tutorial on SQL Joins.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Not sure of the specifics of your data but I think you will want to use an INNER JOIN.