# How can i get data from remote server to my local sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a remote server and on remote server have a SQL server database. I want write this t-sql, for example:

```
INSERT INTO mylocaldatabase
FROM
    remoteserver
WHERE
    remoterserver.id > 100
```

How can I solve this?

thanks for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

Comment: You should use linked server. See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server/22342227#22342227).

Comment: If linking servers is not an option, you will need to investigate bcp to export and import data between the servers. You do realise your example is talking about TABLES, not SERVERS right?

Comment: @RagingBull thanks you my friend to pay attention my problem.its work.