# SQL Store queried data to one table (either temporary or not)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am querying a data from two different servers and now I want to store it on another table so that I can use it as my reference table in my program.. (I am using ASP.NET in programming)

Have a look on my command and please advise what to do.

```
SELECT c.[pf_id]
      ,a.[RequestDate]
      ,c.[pf_carrierUsed]
      ,b.[PiecePrice] * b.[PartQuantity]
      ,c.[pf_type]
      ,c.[pf_resSupplier]
      ,c.[pf_resCustomer]
      ,c.[pf_trailerNum]
      ,b.[PartDesc]
      ,c.[pf_chargeBack]
      ,c.[pf_chargetoPlant]

FROM [CNCTC-WEB01].[NOP_PR].[dbo].[Requests] a
JOIN [CNCTC-WEB01].[NOP_PR].[dbo].[Parts] b on a.[RequestID] = b.[RequestID]
JOIN [PHRIZ-WEBAPP01].[PFTracking].[dbo].[Tbl_PFExcel] c on  b.[PartNumber] like '%'+c.pf_id+'%'
where a.[EntityName] like '%PTA' 
AND a.[RequestDate] between '2015-04-20 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE()
```

The result of this query is what I wanted to store in another table so that I could use it.

Additional :

When I do all use temp_tables i always get :

`String or binary data would be truncated.`

Comment: If you just want to retrieve data from one server and save it into database in another server, you can use `linked server`. Refer [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server/22342227#22342227)

Comment: It's already linked .. My issue here is how to store my queried result into another table ..

Comment: @Anaiah your last edits show that the problem is due to your tables definitions. It seems like your destination table doesn't correspond to the tables from which data are being queried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INSERT` followed by your `SELECT` if your table exists or you can use `SELECT INTO` in order to create the new table.

see

```
 INSERT INTO tempTable
 SELECT c.[pf_id]
  ,a.[RequestDate]
  ,c.[pf_carrierUsed]
  ,b.[PiecePrice] * b.[PartQuantity] AS totalPrice
  ,c.[pf_type]
  ,c.[pf_resSupplier]
  ,c.[pf_resCustomer]
  ,c.[pf_trailerNum]
  ,b.[PartDesc]
  ,c.[pf_chargeBack]
  ,c.[pf_chargetoPlant]

 FROM [CNCTC-WEB01].[NOP_PR].[dbo].[Requests] a
   JOIN [CNCTC-WEB01].[NOP_PR].[dbo].[Parts] b on a.[RequestID] =      b.[RequestID]
   JOIN [PHRIZ-WEBAPP01].[PFTracking].[dbo].[Tbl_PFExcel] c on  b.[PartNumber] like '%'+c.pf_id+'%'
   where a.[EntityName] like '%PTA' 
   AND a.[RequestDate] between '2015-04-20 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE()
```

or

```
 SELECT c.[pf_id]
  ,a.[RequestDate]
  ,c.[pf_carrierUsed]
  ,b.[PiecePrice] * b.[PartQuantity] As TotalPrice
  ,c.[pf_type]
  ,c.[pf_resSupplier]
  ,c.[pf_resCustomer]
  ,c.[pf_trailerNum]
  ,b.[PartDesc]
  ,c.[pf_chargeBack]
  ,c.[pf_chargetoPlant]
 INTO tempTable
 FROM [CNCTC-WEB01].[NOP_PR].[dbo].[Requests] a
   JOIN [CNCTC-WEB01].[NOP_PR].[dbo].[Parts] b on a.[RequestID] =      b.[RequestID]
   JOIN [PHRIZ-WEBAPP01].[PFTracking].[dbo].[Tbl_PFExcel] c on  b.[PartNumber] like '%'+c.pf_id+'%'
   where a.[EntityName] like '%PTA' 
   AND a.[RequestDate] between '2015-04-20 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE()
```

**EDITS.**: `select into` will automatically create tempTable will all columns and let it available for use.

Comment: Then ? I would declare the temp table first ? or create it ?

Comment: Dear @Anaiah , `select into` will automatically create `tempTable` will all columns and let it available for use.

Comment: I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.` in `SELECT INTO tempTable`

Comment: put `into` just before `from`. See how I edited my answer

Comment: `An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name. ` This is what i get again

Comment: @Anaiah: You have a computed column, `b.[PiecePrice] * b.[PartQuantity]`, which you have to give an alias, like so `b.[PiecePrice] * b.[PartQuantity] AS [ColumnName]`

Comment: Thank you @YannickMeeus this helped me to edit my answer once more.

Answer (score 2):

You can create temp table on the fly and then reuse it:

```
select * into #someName
from someTable
join someOtherTable
...
where ...
```

If you already have a table then just `insert select` statement:

```
insert into alreadyCreatedTable
select *
from someTable
join someOtherTable
...
where ...
```

Comment: I tried to but I think i just don't how to use it .. Can u just atleast give me some idea how ?

Comment: What do you mean by `use it`? You can select from it `select * from #someName`, you can use it in joins etc like a regular table.

Comment: `Select * into #newtablename from myTable join someTable where ..` DId you mean like this ?

Comment: Yes, but #newtablename will be temp table that will be available only in current session.

Comment: `String or binary data would be truncated.` is what i get.

Comment: This error tells me nothing without some details. Where do you get this error. What is the statement? Etc