# Executing all the lines before :CONNECT SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

My SQL query looks something like this and am executing it in `SQLCMD` mode in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(acct nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @tempTable (Acct) 
   (select acct from tUsers)

:CONNECT otherserver

USE XXXDb

Select * 
from tUserInfo 
inner join @tempTable on tUserInfo.Acct = @tempTable.Acct
```

GO

The problem is :

Before inserting all the records into `@tempTable`, the `:CONNECT` gets executed. Hence the query fails :( :( :(

Please help me out :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get data form Other server then you can do this;

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(
    acct nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tempTable (Acct) (select acct from tUsers)

Select * from 
[otherserver].[XXXDb].[dbo].[tUserInfo] as ui 
inner join @tempTable on ui.Acct = @tempTable.Acct
GO
```

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server) for how one can query on a DB on other server.