# Report builder 3.0 ssrs join or combine parameters

Tags: join, reporting-services, parameters, report, builder

Say I have parameter YearA and parameter YearB, both are a list of years (2016, 2014, 2014, etc.) BUT since they belong to different databases (and naturally) different datasets, I have 2 parameters scroll-down fields that appear whenever I run the report.

I would like to minimize the number of parameter fields that appear once the report is run. In other words, is there a way to either create a new parameter combining YearA and YearB? Like some sort of a Lookup function or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Are both databases in the same server? If so you could create a datasource with a login that has read permission over both databases, then just create a dataset that uses the previously created datasource and query the databases to get all years from both.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, unfortunately, (to make things more complicated lol) they are from different servers.

Comment: In that case you could link both servers, check these links: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144070/2647648) and [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: Thanks alot Alejandro!

Answer (score 0):

There is no option other than creating a linked server if the data sources are from different servers.

For more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/08/07/dataset-execution-order.aspx