# How to merge informations from two databases by the SQL/T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two databases with stock info. Both of them (among others) contains:

```
SKU;stock_level
```

What I want to get is:

```
SKU;stock_level_warehouse1;stock_level_warehouse2
```

The SKU's are the same at every warehouse, only stock level could be different. How can I merge data from that two databases by the SQL/T-SQL?

---

EDIT (Sample Data)

```
SELECT
    MSSERVER.company1.dbo.vwArticles.article_sku, 
    MSSERVER.company1.dbo.vwArticles.warehouse_id, 
    MSSERVER.company1.dbo.vwArticles.stock_level
FROM
    MSSERVER.company1.dbo.vwArticles
WHERE
    MSSERVER.company1.dbo.vwArticles.warehouse_id = 1
```

In the second query (that I want merge with this above) everything is the same except company name - there is "company2" instead "company1".

As the result I want to get:

```
SKU;STOCK_LEVEL_COMAPNY_1;STOCK_LEVEL_COMPANY_2
```

Comment: Do you mean you have two _tables_, or do you really have two tables in two different _databases_?  Also, if you're not using MySQL, then please remove that tag.

Comment: Nope, I mean two databases exactly. Right - MySQL tag removed :)

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results

Comment: Help for the select from two databases part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your two databases are in the same server:
Database 1: FooDB
Database 2 : FooDB2

```
select t1.id, t2.descr
from [foodb].[dbo].table1 t1
inner join [foodb2].[dbo].table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.table1id
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data I cannot be certain but you just need to `JOIN` your tables.

```
SELECT t1.SKU, t1.stock_level_warehouse1, t2.stock_level_warehouse2
FROM yourtable1 t1
INNER JOIN yourtable2 t2 ON t1.SKU = t2.SKU
```

Comment: its from same DB i guess. but the question is looking for 2 different DB merge.

Comment: Yep. It's the same MS SQL server but two different databases there.

Comment: I provided some sample data at the first post.