# SELECT Query between two different servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I want to pull out data from different tables from different servers. I took a query at `V5\SQL2014` Server and run these following to connect to `V5_27\SQL2005` Server

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
@server= 'V5_27\SQL2005',
@srvproduct='V5_27\SQL2005',
@provider='SQLNCLI', 
@datasrc='tcp:0.0.0.0'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@useself='FALSE',
@rmtsrvname='V5_27\SQL2005',
@rmtuser='sa',
@rmtpassword='123'

SELECT * FROM Stk006,[V5_27\SQL2005]..[TESTACC].Stk006
```

It shows me following errors.

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "V5_27\SQL2005" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "V5_27\SQL2005" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
>
> Msg 10049, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   TCP Provider: The requested address is not valid in its context.

1. `User and Password` are not wrong.
2. `Allow remote` is enabled in both servers.
3. `TCP/IP and Named Pipes` are enabled in both servers.

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: I am sure, it is a memory issue or network traffic error. Instead, i would rather really create a synonym and execute from the server. Might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I found a solution for my problem.

You can check the solution link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server) or do below steps.

1. Try to create a linkServer , Object Explorer -> Server Objects -> Linked Servers (Right click and create new)

[image]

2. Configure Settings

Enter your Server Name
[image]

Login with `sa` and `password`

[image]

3. Then Test Connection of it.

[image]

4. Enjoy your query.

`select
    lc.t2 as 'Local Stock Code',
    ext.t2 as 'External Stock Code'
from
    Stk001 lc,
    [V5_27\SQL2005].[TESTACC].[dbo].[STK001] ext`