# Access MySQL database object of another MySQL server's database

Tags: mysql

I have 2 databases on the two different servers. I am using `MySQL`

Server 1 has the Database: **LookupDB**
Server 2 has the Database: **TranscationDB**

Now, I want to create one stored procedure in `TranscationDB` which needs some data from `LookupDB`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can, it's called `Linked Servers`. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

Comment: ` Linked Servers` is for SQL server, and my question is for MySQL

Comment: You should specify which tools for mysql are you talking about: command line, phpmysql, ...

Comment: @Mittal got it!

Comment: @kiks73, I am using simple mysql server and any IDE to connect it like workbench, sqlyog etc.. As I mentioned I want to create stored procedure for this