# Querying Across Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to query across servers.

The error message I got was:

> Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.

I found this SO post:

[Stackoverflow Post #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

I am having trouble setting this up though:

Let's say I have the following parameters:

```
user login = 'john.doe'
server = 'abc'
instance = '123'
schema: 'dbo'
database: 'restaurant_menu'
```

sql server version = '2016'

I am not sure how to set this up. This is what I came up with so far. Also, this is just a one-time query that may get ran up to a couple more times, but that is it.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'abc',
@provider = N'SQLNCLI',
@srvproduct = 
@datasrc = 
@location = -- I don't think I need to fill this part out
@provstr =
@catalog =
```

Comment: If it's a one-time query with a fixed (SQL) login, consider using `OPENROWSET` instead of a permanent linked server. (This needs to be enabled with `sp_configure` first, but can be disabled afterwards.)

Comment: This is a useful comment because I had no idea openrowset was even a thing. I looked at the documentation and it does appear that is the way to go. I still need to figure out how to set this up, but thank you for your comment.

Comment: I figured it out using openrowset, sadly this is blocked using some security feature that I was not aware of. Thank you for the help though!