# Attaching several mdf files to a SQL Server instance or extract data and save it to a new database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, data-extraction

We have several engineering projects whose data is finally stored in a `.mdf` SQL Server database file. I now want to centralize all this engineering data and create reports about the different projects.

What would you recommend? Should I attach all the `.mdf` files to a central SQL Server instance, or extract the data from all the `.mdf` files and save them to a new database?

Answer (score 0):

Please Read This Post : (Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for or what I ment. The project data does not run on a server but is effectively stored in an mdf file. The question is which concept is better. Extract (ETL) or attach the several mdf files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)